# Read/Update SharePoint admin center Settings

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, office-365-developer, office365apis

Is it possible to read or even update settings in the SharePoint Admin center via an API or CSOM. The section I would like to access is shown below, this is for SharePoint Online
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**You cant update any of those properties.** only commands available for SharePoint online via powershell were given in the Microsoft article below.

[Reference Link to powershell commands](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-the-SharePoint-Online-Management-Shell-c16941c3-19b4-4710-8056-34c034493429)

Comment: Is it possible to read these settings?

Comment: no its not possible.